# How to stop Microsoft Edge from using a cached redirect?

Tags: redirect, microsoft-edge

I made a mistake in my `.htaccess` file that created redirect from `domain.com` to `domain.com/wiki/wp-wiki/wiki/wp-wiki/wiki/wp-wiki/wiki/wp-wiki/wiki/wp-wiki/wiki/wp-wiki/wiki/wp-wiki/wiki/wp-wiki/wiki/wp-wiki/wiki/wp-wiki/wiki/wp-wiki/wiki/wp-wiki/wiki/wp-wiki/wiki/wp-wiki/wiki/wp-wiki/wiki/wp-wiki/wiki/wp-wiki/wiki/`

Obviously I got a `err too many redirects` when I tested it in Microsoft Edge.

I resolved the issue, and now the website **works perfectly** in every other browser **except Microsoft Edge**.

Edge is still redirecting to that annoying URL.

I've cleared the cookie and cache in Edge countless times with no success, I even restarted the whole computer. I still can't get edge to stop redirecting.

Any ideas why Edge is doing that, but no other browser is?

Thanks!

Comment: If you go to a completely new machine does it have the same issue?

Comment: Does opening dev tools (F12) "fix" the issue? Incognito mode?

Comment: Incognito mode works perfectly.

Opening (F12) and loading the page still causes the same issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks @mjwills

I opened (F12) and right clicked "clear browser cache" and "clear browser cookies". That worked and I am no longer being redirected.

It's weird that it did not work when I clear cache and cookies through the settings menu, but I it only worked when I right clicked in the console.

Something for others to note.

Comment: Clearing the browser cache and cookies also requires you to log in for every site again. Opening developer tools and disable caching in the network tab and reload the original URL again will bypass the cache. Then you can close the developer tools and the old cached value is also gone.

Answer (score 5):

Ramone de Klein added this valuable note. I'm reposting it to raise it's visibility:

Clearing the browser cache and cookies requires you to log in to every site again. Instead: Open **developer tools**, in the **Network** tab, **Disable Caching**. Then and **re-load the original URL**. That step bypasses the cache. When you close the developer tools, the the old cached value is gone.